# How to upload video to Vine programmatically on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, video, vine

What I can find online is all about retrieving information from Vine (through undocumented APIs). How can I upload the video in my app to Vine programmatically?

I just found this app can do this on the app store:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vinyet/id697065371

"For the first time, capture, enhance, and post your videos DIRECTLY to Vine or Instagram."

Comment: Has anyone successfully done this? I'd love to see an implementation

Comment: @phantomlimb Have you found the way to upload the video on VINE?

Comment: @Sudha The accepted answer should work, I never tried though

Comment: Hi Guys!
I have facing same Problem for upload video on vine. I have following same process.   
1.first Login(success)  
2. thumbnails upload(success) 
3. video upload (success) 
4. Create Post response  
{
    code = "";
    data =     {
        created = "2016-04-18T09:27:20.000000";
        permalinkUrl = "https://vine.co/v/iFaqLt7w5Qm";
        postId = 1333777877887795200;
        videoUrl = "http://v.cdn.vine.co/static/private_post_old_client.mp4";
    };
    error = "";
    success = 1;
} 
But upload video never show in vine app  
Please Help me ,Have you any idea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this: https://github.com/VineAPI/VineAPI/blob/master/endpoints.md

You need to use these requests: Login, Upload thumbnail, Upload video, Create post.

I don't know if it works or not, you have to try.
In any case, the use of undocumented (private) API can lead to bad consequences.

Comment: Hi Guys!
I have facing same Problem for upload video on vine. I have following same process.   
1.first Login(success)  
2. thumbnails upload(success) 
3. video upload (success) 
4. Create Post response  
{
    code = "";
    data =     {
        created = "2016-04-18T09:27:20.000000";
        permalinkUrl = "https://vine.co/v/iFaqLt7w5Qm";
        postId = 1333777877887795200;
        videoUrl = "http://v.cdn.vine.co/static/private_post_old_client.mp4";
    };
    error = "";
    success = 1;
} 
But upload video never show in vine app  
Please Help me ,Have you any idea

Comment: Using Above doc api Following all steps. but upload video did not show On vine app after login. Please click on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710365/uploaded-video-did-not-show-on-vine-app
You can see working process and issues.