# Instagram iOS API to Post Video

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, video, instagram

Is there any public API to post a video on Instagram?

We know that on iOS it is possibile to share an image (JPEG or PNG) using the [iPhone Hooks](http://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/) via iOS Document Interaction.
On Android it is possibile to share a video via [Android Intent](http://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/).

The iOS App [Cinamatic](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/cinamatic/id855274310?mt=8) is doing this after oAuth API, but according to [Instagram API documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/) there's no mention to a media object of type 'video'.

We also know that other apps, that are not using Instagram oAuth, will save a video in the Video Folder and then open the Instagram Camera via the mentioned iPhone Hooks, in order to let the user to open that video, but that it is not so smart.

So how Cinamatic is doing this using the API?

Answer (score 2):

The undocumented **Instagram Video Hook** let you share videos to Instagram quite like the [Camera Hook](http://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/)

```
URL: instagram://library
Path parameter: AssetPath
Comment parameter: InstagramCaption
```

and so you have something like

```
NSString *instagramURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@&InstagramCaption=%@",videoURL,[videocaption stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]]];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```

Comment: error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226433/instagram-hooks-pre-select-media-issue

Answer (score 0):

For now Instagram doesn't support any 3rd party directly upload video. There is a discussion about this here: [Posting video on instagram using hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017266/posting-video-on-instagram-using-hooks)

Comment: I recap the status with the only working and approved solution by Instagram, via the Instagram video hook above.

Comment: In theory today December 23, 2015, whether it would be possible, but it is a somewhat confusing documentation