# Instagram hooks pre-select media issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, hook, instagram

This is my code. The file is correctly added to photos library, but in instagram app this url -> `instagram://library?AssetPath=assets-library%3A%2F%2Fasset%2Fasset.mp4%3Fid=5EDBD113-FF57-476B-AABB-6A59F31170B5&ext=mp4&InstagramCaption=my%caption` don't open the last video.

```
- (void)loadCameraRollAssetToInstagram:(NSURL*)assetsLibraryURL andMessage:(NSString*)message
{
    NSString *escapedString   = [self urlencodedString:assetsLibraryURL.absoluteString];
    NSString *escapedCaption  = [self urlencodedString:message];
    NSURL *instagramURL       = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@&InstagramCaption=%@", escapedString, escapedCaption]];

    NSLog(@"instagramURL ==> %@",instagramURL);

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
        NSLog(@"Open Instagram!!");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Cant open Instagram!!");
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Instagram" message:@"App not installed" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
    }
}

- (NSString*)urlencodedString:(NSString *)message
{
    return [message stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
}

- (void)saveToCameraRoll:(NSURL *)srcURL withCurrentAction:(NSString *)action
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock videoWriteCompletionBlock = ^(NSURL *newURL, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            NSLog( @"Error writing image with metadata to Photo Library: %@", error );
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:@"Pal - Currently we can't process your video. Please try again in few moments" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Sign In", nil] show];

        } else {
            NSLog( @"Wrote image with metadata to Photo Library: %@", newURL.absoluteString);
            if ([action isEqualToString:@"instagram"])
                [self loadCameraRollAssetToInstagram:newURL andMessage:@"My caption"]; //Can be any text?
        }
    };

    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:srcURL])
    {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:srcURL completionBlock:videoWriteCompletionBlock];
    }
}
```

[image]

***something very strange is that worked perfect, until I turned uninstall and then install instagram. Do not know if this has something to do***

Comment: did you find an answer?  I am running into the same problem.

Comment: @scientiffic it has not been possible to find a way to fix it, for now I have neglected this ticket.

Comment: @jose920405 sadly news, thank you anyway.

Comment: @jose920405 are you able to find out  LocalIdentifier?

Comment: Sorry @DevangGoswami, I had not had time to try this, because I had abandoned this issue, I had to resume today because I needed this for another project. Check out my recent response ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226433/instagram-hooks-pre-select-media-issue#42398297

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`instagram://library?AssetPath=\(assetsLibraryUrl)`
stopped working a while ago. Instagram developers probably moved to Photos framework and no longer use the AssetsLibrary.

Having this assumption I tried several other parameter names and found that `instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=\(localID)` where `localId` is the `localIdentifier` of your `PHAsset` works for now.

This is still as undocumented as it was so it can break in any future version of the Instagram.

Comment: How to get this LocalIdentifier after save video to gallery?

Comment: @Devang Goswami you can get LocalIdentifier from asset url string.

Comment: Is there any way to share with video URL not with local url?

Answer (score 4):

Resuming this task after a long time and considering the **`borisgolovnev's`** answer and `ALAssetsLibrary` is deprecated, the final solution is:

```
- (void)saveToCameraRollOpt2:(NSURL *)srcURL
{
    __block PHAssetChangeRequest *_mChangeRequest = nil;
    __block PHObjectPlaceholder *placeholder;

    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{

        NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:srcURL];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];

        _mChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];

        placeholder = _mChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset;

    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

        if (success) {
            [self loadCameraRollAssetToInstagram:[placeholder localIdentifier]];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"write error : %@",error);
            [self showAlert:@"Error" msg:@"Error saving in camera roll" action:nil];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)loadCameraRollAssetToInstagram:(NSString *)localId
{
    NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=\%@", localId]];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
    } else {
        [self showAlert:@"Error" msg:@"Instagram app is not installed" action:nil];
    }
}

- (NSString*)urlencodedString:(NSString *)message
{
    return [message stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
}
```

Don't forget

```
#import <Photos/Photos.h>

Add `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` and `QueriesSchemes` inside .plist file

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need permission to access to manage your photos library</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
</array>
```

Comment: How to do it for video ?

Answer (score 1):

@borisgolovnev's solution actually works. You can get the localIdentifier of your last saved video using the code below. Passing it with instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=(localID) opens Instagram with your video selected.

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending:false)]
let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Video, options: fetchOptions)
if let lastAsset = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAsset {
    self.localIdentifier = lastAsset.localIdentifier
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
{
    NSURL *videoFilePath = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[request downloadDestinationPath]]]; // Your local path to the video
    NSString *caption = @"Some Preloaded Caption";
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoFilePath completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
        NSString *escapedString   = [self urlencodedString:videoFilePath.absoluteString];
        NSString *escapedCaption  = [self urlencodedString:caption];
        NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@&InstagramCaption=%@",escapedString,escapedCaption]];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
        }
    }];
}
```

Instagram will only shows those iamges/videos which are saved at path which you set in instagramURL. That path should be absolute.

If it still not shows then add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in info.plist file of array, add its item0 as instagram.

Comment: Unfortunately I think the "AssetPath" argument has been removed from the instagram custom URL scheme: https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/ (as has the "InstagramCaption")

Comment: and what is the difference with the code for the question?

Comment: Yes, you are right, i have not checked this in iOS9. Let me find a new way to open it. There is nothing much details on their developer site.

Comment: Thank you my friend, I appreciate it

Comment: @PratikPatel Any developments on the AssetPath problem?

Comment: How can I upload video to instagram ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
- (NSString*)urlencodedString:(NSString *)message{
return [message stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
}
```

With

```
- (NSString*)urlencodedString:(NSString *)message{
return [message stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
}
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

**swift 3** get the latest Identifier **simple and fast**

```
  var lastIdentifier = ""
  let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
  fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending:false)]
  let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions)
  if let lastAsset: PHAsset = fetchResult.lastObject {
    lastIdentifier = lastAsset.localIdentifier
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for sharing video on instagram : 
May be you need to add condition for `substringFromIndex` but its working.

```
 - (void)ShareAssetURLvideoToInstagram:(NSURL*)assetsLibraryURL
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *queryStringDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            NSString *strParamater = [assetsLibraryURL.absoluteString substringFromIndex:[assetsLibraryURL.absoluteString rangeOfString:@"?"].location+1];
            NSArray *urlComponents = [strParamater componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
            for (NSString *keyValuePair in urlComponents)
            {
                NSArray *pairComponents = [keyValuePair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
                NSString *key = [[pairComponents firstObject] stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
                NSString *value = [[pairComponents lastObject] stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];

                [queryStringDictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
            }

            NSString *mediaId = [queryStringDictionary valueForKey:@"id"];

            if (mediaId.length > 0) {
                NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=%@",mediaId]];

                if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score -4):

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
NSLog(@"Open Instagram!!"); //enter code here
[[UIApplication sharedApplication/*<enter your code here>*/] openURL:instagramURL];
```

Comment: I can not understand you. You could be a little clearer

Comment: Please elaborate on how this answers the question.