# Instagram hooks pre-select video while upload video to instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

Already have this problem but no solution yet. If you check [Instagram hooks pre-select media issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226433/instagram-hooks-pre-select-media-issue) then you will understand the problem.

But I am not getting solution when I am trying to upload video to instagram.Library is showing and it's video also showing but last downloaded video in the library file is not pre-selected.