# How can you launch Instagram's new post screen from another iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, instagram, instagram-api

A few apps are able to launch Instagram's "create post" screen on iPhone, with 1 tap, and pass a photo or video to populate the new post. These apps include Everalbum and Musical.ly.

They are not using the document interaction API Instagram has documented. That method shows the standard iOS share control, and adds an option for "Copy to Instagram". These apps are much more user friendly, and just launch Instagram create-post screen directly with no additional taps or popups. Documentation on the less ideal approach is here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/

Any idea what API these apps are using to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try to use answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017266/posting-video-on-instagram-using-hooks)?

Comment: what about musical.ly ? is there any information how to launch and share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great post on this subject [here](http://blog.horizon.camera/post/102273431070/video-share-objc-ios-instagram).  Basically you launch Instagram using their app URL scheme and pass a URL referencing the content in the camera roll.

Comment: Worked with slight tweak, for iOS 9's PhotoLibrary API I had to use the parameters described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35099786/4076298

Comment: @TomSwift hey, do you know how to make that for Musical,ly? Thanks!