# How do I share a Video on Instagram in iOS/Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram-api

I am building an app and one of the requirements is sharing a video on Instagram.

FB and Twitter works fine, but Instagram documentation is not clear enough. 
Is it possible to share a video on Instagram? if yes then how?

I found that Magisto app does it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Posting video on instagram using hooks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017266/posting-video-on-instagram-using-hooks)

Comment: Don't just ask for code.  What have you tried?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The current instagram API doesn't allow for posting to instagram, only reading data and posting comments and likes:

- basic - to read data on a user’s behalf, e.g. recent media, following lists (granted by default)
- comments - to create or delete comments on a user’s behalf
- relationships - to follow and unfollow accounts on a user’s behalf
- likes - to like and unlike media on a user’s behalf

For any of them other than 'basic', first you need to submit your app for review. (With instagram: https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116)