# Uploaded Video did not show on vine app

Tags: ios, video, file-upload

I found this: https://github.com/VineAPI/VineAPI/blob/master/endpoints.md

I have following Some Process for share video on vine app.
**1.Login:**https://api.vineapp.com/users/authenticate
Authentication successfully using above doc lin API. I have received a key(session key).
[image]

for another  Process. 
After that use the next Api for Upload Video thumbnail On Vine.
**2.thumnails** 
https://media.vineapp.com/upload/thumbs/1.3.1.mp4.jpg

[image]

Thumbnails successfully uploaded On vine and received the server response
 get the uploaded thumbnails URL in **X-Upload-Key**. You can see the Above image.
**3.Upload Video**:https://media.vineapp.com/upload/videos/1.3.1.mp4
[image]

Video Data successfully uploaded On vine and received the server response
 get the uploaded Video URL in **X-Upload-Key**. You can see the Above image.
**4.Create Post:**https://api.vineapp.com/posts
[image]

Post successfully create On vine and received the server response

```
{
code = "";
data =     {
    created = "2016-04-18T09:27:20.000000";
    permalinkUrl = "https://vine.co/v/iFaqLt7w5Qm";
    postId = 1333777877887795200;
    videoUrl = "http://v.cdn.vine.co/static/private_post_old_client.mp4";
};
error = "";
success = 1;
```

}

When Open the  permalinkUrl = "https://vine.co/v/iFaqLt7w5Qm"; get error message.You can see in Image
[image]

and aslo open link on browser 
http://v.cdn.vine.co/static/private_post_old_client.mp4

Video autometically download but video did not download actual video.show some message On Video Like this.
[image]

Please Help me.Have you any Idea.

Comment: Hi, Jeet, I am also facing the same problem, It has been a month you uploaded this question, did you found any solution for this. Please update here if you have one. Thanks

Comment: No Sir, I m waiting for any positive  response.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it,

Just change the setting of AVAssetExportSession before exporting the video to save.

self.exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition
                                                                          presetName:AVAssetExportPreset640x480];

self.exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;

Comment: Hi, Kalu ji,

but My Video Resolution is same as you video resolution. 
Can you explain upload Video on vine process step by step , or  If have you any demo Please share Link for vine upload feature.
:) Please share me Demo.